# How can I check this volume comparison?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, inequalities, geometric-analysis

I am reading the paper [Ricci Curvature and Volume Convergence](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2951841?seq=1) written by Professor Colding. In section 2, they define Lipschitz functions $b_j^+:M\to\mathbb R$ with $|\nabla b_j^+|=1$ and set $$\Phi=(b_1^+,...,b_n^+):B_1(p)\to B_{1+\epsilon}(0)\subset\mathbb R^n.$$ Then, why do we have $\text{Vol}(\Phi(B_1(p)))\leq\text{Vol}(B_1(p))$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By approximation, we may assume that the map $\Phi$ is continuously differentiable. Then the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant of $\Phi$ is the volume of a parallelepiped with edge lengths $1$ and hence with volume $\le1$. So, the absolute value of the Jacobian determinant of $\Phi$ is $\le1$, and the volume comparison follows.

Comment: Is the approximation argument necessary? After all Lipschitz functions are differentiable almost everywhere. Not a big deal in any case...

Comment: @LeoMoos : I thought about that. But then you also need a bit more general theorem about change of variables in a multifold integral, a reference to which I don't happen to know at the moment.

Comment: That's fair. I suspect 'under the hood' there might be an approximation argument regardless.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!